# How to use compass mixins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

I have rails on my backend and angularjs on my frontend. I've added compass-rails gem and now I can write css.scss files.
I don't have compass configuration file (don't know where to put it exactly and not sure if I need it at all).
I want to use compass mixins without changing my directory structure, just to import something and thats it. Is there any use to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to configure your extra files for mixins just create `_mixin.scss` (name it whatever you need with undescore on front)  file in stylesheets directory and import it onto ur `css.scss` file.

for example.

i think you configured gem like this

```
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
end
```

now create your mixin file as mentioned above and import it like `@import "mixins";` on your `index.css.scss` file in stylesheets folder..:)